# how to create package that will access URL

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

In SSIS, I have developed one package which will access data using API(with the help of URL).
This package failed when URL is not accessible/available(if server is not available URL is not able to access data ) using SSIS package.
Now, I have to enhance this package in such a way that package will never fail even though  URL is not available and will complete successfully so other packages are in queue completed without interrupt and send email to recipient commenting URL is not available for a package.

Could you please help me how to achieve this in SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using an Event Handler. On the TRY sequence container, set up an 'OnError' event handler. You can set `@[System::Propagate]` to false, preventing the error from stopping your package, and put any other actions you want to execute in case of an error, like saving the error details to a log.